# Creating a TABLE to pivot and concat columns from exiting table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a Table that stores customer Dynamic values from the Forms that they create.

The Table is called **Dynamic_Fields_T** and is formatted like this:

```
ID  | FIELD_NAME 
1   |  TANK  
2   | PRODUCT TYPE 
3   | ODOMETER 
4   | RECEIPT #
```

This is not joinable to our ticket Tables.

I need this to appear like this:

```
ID_1 | ID_2 .......ID_N

TANK | PRODUCT_TYPE  ......N
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some example data as text please and expected results?

Comment: A view is just like a saved query. Any *particular* query always produces a result set with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types. However, what you're asking for is a query with a variable number of columns in its result set. That doesn't exist. You can construct a query on-the-fly, a.k.a dynamic SQL, but you're not going to be building such a query *inside* a view.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: Ok, I am a complete newbie to this and was given a project....Maybe Dynamic SQL is what I need and not a View. I just need this table Pivoted...I am not using SQL 2008 by choice, it is what my company uses. I would much rather use MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your **[ID]** column is unique you can use a dynamic `select` statement with an aggregation function (`min` or `max`) to return all your rows in a single row:

```
--create test table
create table #Dynamic_Fields_T (
    [ID] INT
    ,[FIELD_NAME] varchar(max)
    )

--populate test table
insert into #Dynamic_Fields_T
values 
 (1   ,'TANK')
,(2   ,'PRODUCT TYPE') 
,(3   ,'ODOMETER') 
,(4   ,'RECEIPT #') 

declare @sql nvarchar(max) =''

--build dynamic columns
select 
    @sql = @sql + ',max(case when [ID] = ''' + cast([ID] as varchar) + ''' then [FIELD_NAME] end) as [ID_' + cast([ID] as varchar) + ' ] '
from 
    #Dynamic_Fields_T

--build dynamic query, remove unnecessary comma
select @sql = 'select ' + stuff(@sql, 1 , 1, '') + ' from #Dynamic_Fields_T'

--execute dynamic query
execute (@sql)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Exactly What I was looking for and Based on my question, you answered it Brilliantly....I was hoping to make this Dynamic for Field Names as well as Clients do their forms different based on their needs..so one client could have id_1 as Tank, but another may have ID_1 = Gross Gallons. This definitely gave me the structure I was looking for though...Any help on the second part?

Comment: Nevermind....I realize the second part was the answer....Your a Godsend!!!